# intellij 11.0.2 code highlighting analysis does not complete

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij CE 11.0.2 with Maven and IdeaVIM on Windows 7.

When I import a certain file into my java source file:

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponentPanel;
```

The code highlighting analysis (which marks colored lines on the side of the editor and a little colored square at the top right of the editor) stays as an eye indicating that its still processing, it doesn't complete.

If I comment out that import then the code highlighting analysis completes (with errors), also the code highlighting analysis in other files in my project stops working (doesn't complete)

Is there anyway to fix this or at least localize it to the one file, any suggestions ideas welcome

Comment: CrazyCoder that worked a treat! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of such weird problems the first thing you should try is `File` | `Invalidate Caches`.

Comment: Yes, this usually fixes most problems, but on a rare occasion the problem persists even after rebuilding the caches. I have this problem now with 14.1.1 on just one small java file.